# Java Process executes "pdflatex" successfully but generates empty .pdf file

Tags: java

I want to compile a .tex file from a Java program. I wrote the following code, and it successfully executes, but when I try to open the `.pdf` file generated, the OS pops a message saying that the file is completely empty ([link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNcfx.png)).

By the way, when I run the command `pdflatex tarea0.tex` directly from terminal, it generates the non-empty .pdf file I want to get from the Java program.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("pdflatex", "tarea0.tex");
            pb.directory(new File("/Users/carlosreategui/coding/java_testing/latex"));
            Process p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the link to all the files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d-cUyB3SaEJVPxpNL8ypG3FrhLDWBOEC?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the process to conclude. I'm guessing that exiting the JVM before waiting for the process to conclude causes `pdflatex` to receive a signal causing it to terminate abruptly.

So adding a line:

```
p.waitFor();
```

after the `p.start()` should have the desired effect.